# getCSSProperties gives out a Javascript bug

Tags: javascript, css

```
function getStyle(el, cssprop) {
  if (el.currentStyle) { // IE
    return el.currentStyle[cssprop];
  } else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) { // Firefox
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop];
  } else { // try and get inline style
    return el.style[cssprop];
  }
}
```

When called it gives out this error
It gives out this error

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop];
```

So the function call is `findOpacity(window.thirddiv,1)`. `findOpacity` calls `getStyle`. The code for `findOpacity` is like this:

```
function findOpacity(node, minValue) {
    if(node==document.body) {
        return getStyle(document.body, 'opacity') < minValue
            ? getStyle(document.body, 'opacity')
            : minValue;
    } else {
        return findOpacity(node.parentNode, getStyle(node.parentNode, 'opacity'))
            < minValue
            ? findOpacity(node.parentNode, getStyle(node.parentNode, 'opacity'))
            : minValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, but it's not well supported in browsers.

Comment: What exactly is `el`?

Comment: @jimmyweb I have hence tested for all browsers.Do u have a better function to get CSSProperties.Thanks

Comment: @SLaks el is element for which the css properties are defined

Comment: And where I call this function el does exist.Its not undefined.

Comment: please describe what do you want to achieve, because code taken out of context is useless

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. How do you call the function?

Comment: So the function call is findOpacity(window.thirddiv,1).findOpacity calls getStyle.The code for findOpacity is like this                                 function findOpacity(node, minValue) {
    if(node==document.body) {
        return getStyle(document.body, 'opacity') < minValue ? getStyle(document.body, 'opacity') : minValue;
    } else {
        return findOpacity(node.parentNode, getStyle(node.parentNode, 'opacity')) < minValue ? findOpacity(node.parentNode, getStyle(node.parentNode, 'opacity')) : minValue;
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is causing you problem, but try

```
function findOpacity(node, maxValue) {
    var val = node===document.body
        ? getStyle(document.body, 'opacity')
        : findOpacity(node.parentNode);
    if(maxValue !== void(0)) val = Math.min(val, maxValue);
    return +val;
}
```

Note that you should avoid things like

```
getStyle(document.body, 'opacity') < minValue
    ? getStyle(document.body, 'opacity')
    : minValue;
```

because you can be calculating `getStyle(document.body, 'opacity')` twice. Moreover, `minValue` is a maximum value instead of minimum one.

**Your problem**

The problem is that `window.thirddiv` is not an html element, but an [XPC wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCNativeWrapper). And you can't use `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle` with XPC wrappers.

My guess is that you are programming a GreaseMonkey script with privileges. Then, you should read http://wiki.greasespot.net/XPCNativeWrappers, and to get the real html element, use `window.thirddiv.wrappedJSObject`. The problem is that your code will be vulnerable, and malicious scripts could gain access to privileged methods like `GM_xmlhttpRequest`.

If you aren't creating a GM script, you could unwrap th XPC wrapper using `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(obj)`. Again, this is an unsafe practice.

Comment: @SwarajChhatre It works for me. I think that your `window.thirddiv` is not an html element.

Comment: window.thirddiv gives ot <div id="ThirdTest"> on console.It does exist.

Comment: @SwarajChhatre Ah wait. It's not an html element, but an [XPC wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCNativeWrapper)

Comment: window.thirddiv.wrappedJSObject gives out 'undefined'.

Comment: Not all XPC wrappers have [`wrappedJSObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/wrappedJSObject) attribute. Then, try `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap`.

Comment: ReferenceError: XPCNativeWrapper is not defined

Comment: Where are you running your code? Is it a privileged environment? Why do you have `XPCNativeWrapper` variables? Please explain it all. And I don't know much about `XPCNativeWrapper`, so maybe you should ask another question about how to deal with it